# How come e becomes ln()

Tags: calculus

What kind of rule or formula this kind of equations uses?

For example we have:

$$a=e^{x}$$

How come it is equal to:

$$\ln a =x$$

Tried to find some kind of rule for that about how it works, but didn't found anything.

Comment: Are you familiar with the *inverse* of a function, as a general concept?  This is a particular case of a function's inverse.

Comment: it's its inverse!

Comment: Instead of using the Google API to produce an *image* of an equation, you can [post mathematical expressions](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) here using $\LaTeX$ syntax.

Comment: Okey thanks for info @hardmath

Comment: And oh yes, right, it is the inverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note $\log_a x$ is the inverse of the function $a^x$.  When we speak of the natural log of $x$, it is written $\ln(x)$, which is simply shorthand for $\log_e(x)$.

$$a = e^x$$

Since $\log x$, or in this case the natural log $\log_e x = \ln x$ is a strictly increasing function, we can take the $\ln$ of both sides to get:
$$\ln(a) = \ln(e^x) = x\ln(e) = x$$

Note that for any real $a, b$, be have $\underbrace{\log_a(a^b) =  b\log_a(a)}_{\log x^y = y \log x} = b\cdot 1 = b$.

Comment: You're welcome. RedRose.

Comment: Btw how come b*1=1?

Comment: Because $\log_a(a) = 1,$  just like $\log_2(2) = 1$, just as $\ln(e) = 1$.  If we raise each side of $\log_e(e) = \ln(e)= 1$, as a power a power of e, we have $e^{\ln e} = e^1 \iff \ln e = 1$

Comment: Yes right, I understood that log_a(a) = 1, but shouldn't  b*1=b?

Comment: Yikes!  Major typo, yes you're spot on. Corrected.

Comment: Okey, thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

The rule we have is the definition of [logarithim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm).The logarithim, by definition is the inverse of the exponential function.

Note that by the definition of logarithim $$a=b^{x}$$ becomes $$\log_{b} a=x$$
Yours is just a case when $b=e$. Note $\log_{e} x =\ln x$.If you're curious about $\log$ and $\ln$, see more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_logarithm).